# Grant OAuth App Access To Organisation After Revoking

Tags: github, github-organizations

I did the mistake of Revoking Access to an organisation. Now I can't seem to Grant Access to it again.

In the screenshot below, you can see that on the app's settings page there is no way to grant access to the second organisation. This is the organisation that I initially clicked the `Grant Access` button for, and then clicked the `Revoke` button.

**How can I Grant the app Access to this organisation again?**

---

[image]

---

**And the audit log just taunts me:**

---

[image]

---

> In case you are wondering, it was all done in a Homer fashion
>  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Article: https://help.github.com/articles/approving-third-party-applications-for-your-organization/

Using the steps in the article above, I managed to resolve the issue. Basically, navigate to the Organisation page that you are managing, and then see the screenshot below.

[image]

Followed by

[image]